# Ubuntu 16 - display port no sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio, hdmi, displayport

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Nvidia Quadro K1000M
- Nvidia driver 418

I want to connect my laptop to TV, but the laptop has only a display port so I have bought hdmi to display port adapter which supports audio and video transfer. A video transfer works fine but I can't play sound from the TV speakers.
System settings / Sound doesn't contain any option besides Speakers (Built-in Audo). Even when I disable a laptop screen sound is still played from the laptop speakers. How to fix that ?

Comment: Connect another cable from your laptop into the TV's audio.  Converters have notoriously bad Linux support.